# IJulia installation : miniconda installation infinite loop

Tags: julia, miniconda, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to install IJulia ( I ran `Pkg.add("IJulia")` and now running `Pkg.build("IJulia")` says the package is installed ), but constantly getting these messages for a long while now :

```
INFO: Downloading miniconda installer ...
INFO: Installing miniconda ...
```

And it keeps going, It also occasionally gets ~50% CPU usage.

I have full Anaconda Python installed (Py3) in Windows 10. So is that the issue ? Nothing happened when I tried installing it on my other Linux machine.

EDIT: Removing and re-installation didn't work, neither did setting Anaconda Jupyter as Jupyter environment for Julia. I get an old version error, as it detects that my Jupyter is of version 0.0.0 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar symptoms installing IJulia on my Windows computer.  I was not able to determine what was preventing the Julia package manager from installing miniconda, but I was able to work around the issue by manually installing Miniconda and Jupyter and setting ENV["JUPYTER"] to the full path, including executable name, of the jupyter program.  Without the executable name it reported version 0.0.0 as your question indicated and then fell back to install miniconda (which failed repeatedly).

```
julia> ENV["JUPYTER"]="<HOME>\\Miniconda2\\Scripts\\jupyter.exe"
"<HOME>\\Miniconda2\\Scripts\\jupyter.exe"

julia> Pkg.build("IJulia")
...
INFO: Building IJulia
INFO: Found Jupyter version 4.3.0: <HOME>\Miniconda2\Scripts\jupyter.exe
INFO: Installing Julia kernelspec julia-0.6
[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec julia-0.6 in <HOME>\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\julia-0.6

julia> using IJulia
INFO: Precompiling module IJulia.

julia> notebook()
```

Like you, I did not encounter this problem on my Linux install.  The Readme.md states on Linux it will look for jupyter in your path, but on Mac and Windows it will default to installing miniconda for itself which failed.  Based on your question I think you want to use your preexisting Jupyter install so this should work.  The miniconda install problem may need to be reported as an issue to the IJulia folks as a separate problem.